# Internship in Norway: Which category to report to the directorate of immigration for residency?

Tags: residency, norway, internship

I'm a Dutch student enrolled at a Dutch university who is going to do an internship in Norway. The internship will take 4 months, but I will stay there for 7 months in total. Afterward, I'm planning to look for further employment in the country.

I'm wondering which category I should report to the Directorate of Immigration (UDI) when applying for residency for this period. A [quick search on their website](https://udi.no/en/want-to-apply/residence-under-the-eueeu-regulations/?c=nld) reveals there are a bunch of categories that could be applicable: Student, employee, job seeker, a person with own funds. However, when looking into these categories, I can't find an immediately obvious category for my situation.

### Student

From the [description of this category](https://udi.no/en/want-to-apply/residence-under-the-eueeu-regulations/student-who-are-eueea-national/?c=nld), it's unclear whether I should be registered at a Norwegian educational institute or not:

> - You have been admitted to an accredited educational institution or an upper secondary school.

In my case, I am not affiliated with any Norwegian educational institute.

### Employee

To be an [employee](https://udi.no/en/want-to-apply/residence-under-the-eueeu-regulations/employee-who-is-an-eueea-national/?c=nld), I need to have a job in Norway. Although interns do things that closely resemble the duties of a job, my internship agreement specifically says I won't be employed by my host company:

> The Internship is designed to expand the Intern’s knowledge, skills, and experience for the benefit of their Study program. As such, this Internship Agreement does not seek to serve as a contract of employment under the terms of Article 7:610 of the Dutch Civil Code, nor is it intended to be as such either.

### Job seeker

> If you came to Norway to look for work, you can stay here for six months.
>
> - If you do not get a job within six months, you must leave Norway.
> - You can then come back to Norway anytime to search for work. You can be here for six months, and must report to the police again no later than three months after you came back to Norway.

[This one](https://udi.no/en/want-to-apply/work-immigration/duty-to-report-for-job-seekers-who-are-eueea-nationals/?c=nld) sounds most applicable, however, I already have a position...
That being said, this category does cover almost my entire intended duration of stay in the country. Since it is so easy to 'renew' the job-seeking residency, I could do so by re-entering the country after the Christmas holidays, which will give me the 7th month as well.

Which category would be best to report to the UDI for an internship without employment status?

Comment: currently facing a similar situation. OP, what did you apply for?

Comment: In the end, I took my internship contract and my rental contract to the UDI to sort it out. They assigned me to the category 'person with own funds' (idk what its officially called), based on my internship compensation and my savings. I didn't have the official amount of money required in this category, but just confirming that the compensation and my savings were enough to sustain me while I was there, got me the category and the D-number.